# Overwrite Page Render method .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net, render, overwrite

I would like to capture page source of a webpage by overriding page render method.
I use the following code:

```
 Dim pageSource As String = ""
    Using sw = New StringWriter()
        Using htw = New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
            MyBase.Render(htw)
            pageSource = sw.ToString()
        End Using
    End Using
```

The code works fine on .NET Framework 3.5 However, on .NET 4.0,

### the pageSource variable includes strange tags as below:

```
<$A$>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
</$A$><$B$><head><$C$><title>

</title></$C$></head></$B$><$D$>
<body>
    </$D$><$E$><form name="form1" method="post" action="Default2.aspx" id="form1">
<div>
</div>
<$F$>
    <div> 
    </div>
    </$F$></form></$E$><$G$>
</body>
</html>
</$G$>
```

---

Why do you think this happens?